# Post Visual Studio 2017 Installation, SharePoint Online Management Shell is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, visual-studio-2017

Post Visual Studio 2017 Installation, SharePoint Online Management Shell is not working. While starting Shell, i am getting the error below error. Earlier it was working fine. Anyone got the same error ? VS2017 is working fine and i do not see any issues with it so far.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After trying lot of options, nothing worked. Including Re-installing the SPOL and Visual Studio.

Finally, found the solution. The Execution policy is being reset after installing VS2017. Overiding the Execution policy to remote signed resolved the issue.

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned